# How can I keep the 18th decimal place?

Tags: python

```
my_number = 42379943902701922
print(my_number * 10**-18)
```

Expected output: `0.042379943902701922`

Actual output:   `0.04237994390270192`

Actual output is missing one 2 at the end. Why is that so and how can I arrive at the expected output?

Comment: Floating point doesn't have enough bits to keep that digit.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html ... as an alternative, use `Decimal` https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) help at all?

Comment: `print(f'{my_number * 10**-18:.18f}')` - it gives me 18th place but it has value `3` instead of `2` because float can't keep the exact value. Using `.60f` I get `0.042379943902701923408304907070487388409674167633056640625000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `Decimal`, you can use the `BigFloat` [library for precise decimal numbers](https://pypi.org/project/bigfloat/). Example:

```py
from bigfloat import *

precise_number =  BigFloat('0.042379943902701922', precision(18))
```

Alternatively, to do the calculation:

```py
with precision(18) + RoundTowardZero:
    print(BigFloat.exact(my_number * 10**-18))
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Python interprets any number that includes a decimal point as a double-precision floating point number. However, you can bypass that by using the [**decimal**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module, which provides support for correctly rounded decimal floating point arithmetic.

**Example:**

```
getcontext().prec = 28
Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
```

**Output:**

```
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

Comment: I think better example could be `Decimal(42379943902701922) / Decimal(10**18)` like in OP question.

Answer (score 0):

Thats how its getting printed in console/terminal. You can convert to string while printing if you want to see all the digits

```py
# How it gets printed
>>> print(my_number * 10**-18)
0.04237994390270192

# How its stored
>>> my_number
42379943902701922

# How to print all the digits
>>> print(str(my_number))
42379943902701922

# Or with repr
>>> repr(my_number)
'42379943902701922'
```